# $\int M(f(x)) \mu(dx) = \int_S \int_0^\infty I_{( u < f(x))} v(du)\mu(dx)$

Tags: analysis, probability-theory, proof-explanation

Suppose $(S, \mathcal S, \mu)$ is a probability space. Let $f$ be a nonnegative measurable function on $S$. Let $v$ be a measure on $\mathcal B([0,\infty))$ such that $M(u) = v([0,u)) < \infty$, for all $u$ in $\mathbb R$.

We have $$M(f(x)) = \int_{[0,\infty)} I_{[0,f(x))} dv,$$

but the proof starts with

$$\int M(f(x)) \mu(dx) = \int_S \int_0^\infty I_{( u < f(x))} v(du)\mu(dx)$$

Why the integrand is $I_{( u < f(x))}$ but not $I_{[0,f(x))}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For clarity write $\int_{[0,\infty)} I_{[0,f(x))} dv$ as $\int_{[0,\infty)} I_{[0,f(x))}(u) dv(u)$. The inequality $0\leq u <f(x)$ 
holds iff $f(x) >u$. There is  nothing more to it.

Comment: $[0, f(x))$ = u< f(x)$? The right hand side looks odd.

Comment: @user398843 $I_{u<f(x)}$ actually stands for $I_A(u)$ where $A=\{u: u <f(x)\}$.